# Is Android SDK not supported by windows vista?

Tags: android

I have installed Java, Eclipse and Android SDk in my laptop. But it's OS is windows vista. While downloading the sdk files in the eclipse my system is getting crashed. Is Android not supported by Windows Vista?

Comment: To be pedantic...  Of course not!  Why would Vista "support" a competing product?  What you really want to know, is whether the Android SDK supports Windows Vista. (that is, the converse).

Answer (score 0):

It should work in Vista. Are you downloading the Android SDK or the ADT plugin?

The SDK should be able to be downloaded directly from Android's website (don't need Eclipse), whereas the ADT plugin is installed in Eclipse. Try launching Eclipse with Administrator privileges and see if that solves your problem.